# Relationship fault error in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm using Core Data in one of my app. There is one to many relationship between two entities

Event
(eventId, comments)

Comment
(commentId, remark)

From service API I get event list, comment list and relation ship between two in another block. So I'm updating the comment. It's working fine while I update. But while I'm trying to access all the comments for particular event

```
<relationship fault: 0x7fad45884760 'comments'>
```

Below is my code to fetch particular object based on ID

```
static func fetchObjectWithId(key: String, value: CVarArgType, context: NSManagedObjectContext, entityName: String) -> CoreDataBase!{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    if let val = value as? Int32{
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %d", key, val)
    }
    else{
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K contains[c] %@", key, value)
    }


    do{
        let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        if result.count == 1{
            if let data = result[0] as? CoreDataBase{
                return data
            }
            return nil
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    }
    catch{
        let saveError = error as NSError
        print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

[image]

Please help me. Where am I making mistake.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are trying to fetch the data?

Comment: @KunalShrivastava I had updated the question

Comment: Where are you seeing the "relationship fault" message, exactly? And in what specific way is your code not working?

Answer (score 1):

Faults are lazily fetched when you access them for the first time. If you want your fetch request to fetch the to-many relationship objects then you can add this:

```
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = "Events-Comments Relationship Name"
```